# Right way to fetch mysql data

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 mysql tables as follows:

1. tblEvents - which has fields *id*, **album_id**, *etc.*
2. tblImages - which has fields *id*, *images* and **album_id**

I am fetching data from tblEvents as follows:

```
<?php
$sqlBlog = "SELECT * FROM tblEvents";  
$myBlog = mysql_query($sqlBlog, $con);  
while($blog = mysl_fetch_array($myBlog)){  
$port = '<div>Album Id:'.$blog['album_id'].'</div>'
echo $port;  
}
```

Now, I want to fetch all images from tblImages that has the corresponding **album_id**. Note that **album_id** is the same in both the tables. I want to echo the images in `<li></li>` within the above div. What is the best way to do that??

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: you can use mysql Join : http://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/joins/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN` for this. Have a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/join.html

An example query could look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblEvents events
JOIN tblImages images
ON images.album_id = events.album_id
```

Note that `events` and `images` are now aliases for the tables `tblEvents` and `tblImages`
Now you could even select both ids in the same query by prepending said aliases like so:

```
SELECT images.album_id, events.album_id
FROM tblEvents events
JOIN tblImages images
ON images.album_id = events.album_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  tblEvents AS e
  INNER JOIN tblImages AS i
    ON i.album_id = e.album_id
```

Use this query and try also implment mysqli or PDO

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot seem to get it to work. See [this](http://pastebin.com/6Udh5mpz). This code does not work. When I put the 2nd while loop outside the 1st, it works but it gets the last value of 'image' that the 1st loop ends at. But I need to work it within the 1st loop. I am sorry if this is a silly question but I am completely new to PHP development.